# C# Primary constructor with body?

Tags: c#, .net-8.0, c#-12.0, primary-constructor

Can I use a primary constructor and also define a constructor body?

Here is my attempt using a helper secondary constructor - I realize `this` is ambiguous, but I don't know if there is way to fix it... or do I have to resort to fields?

```
public class Thing(int a, int b) {
    public Thing(int a, int b) : this(a ,b) {
        // do some stuff using `a` and `b`
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd have to use different parameters, or define a static factory method.

Comment: If you need a constructor body for that set of parameters, a primary constructor is not right for that class.

Comment: What do you want to do specifically? Depending on that, you might not actually need a constructor body.

Comment: @Sweeper The ctor needs to take a path and create that directory if it does not exist. The caller expects it to be there and I can't change that, so I can't move that logic anywhere else. I can use a normal ctor, it's just tedious to copy all the args into instance fields, so I was looking to get around that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to have some logic in constructor just use the regular one, I would argue that there is no point in using primary constructors here since they were not designed for such things. If for some reason you still want to you can consider some I would argue ugly hacks.

For example adding a dummy parameter to the primary ctor:

```cs
public class Thing(int a, int b, object? _) 
{
    public Thing(int a, int b) : this(a ,b, null) {
        // do some stuff using `a` and `b`,
        Console.WriteLine($"{a}_{b}");
    }
}
```

Or introducing some dummy field to makes some static callable method to do the job and assign the value:

```
public class Thing(int a, int b)
{
    private int _ = DoThing(a, b);

    private static int DoThing(int a, int b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{a}_{b}");
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

As I said the workarounds are not pretty and in my opinion it's better to stick with "ordinary" ctors.

Also note that at least some IDEs (don't have VS available at the moment) like Rider provide a refactoring which will expand the primary ctor into ordinary one:

[image]

[image]

[image]

So you can start designing class with primary ctor and then expand it into an ordinary one so it can save you some work you consider tedious (also Rider/Resharper can generate the fields and assignment for you too with ordinary ctor).

Comment: I would never have thought of these hacks! They really are awful to look at, 100% agree with just making a normal constructor instead